# Matplotlib should start from 0 on x axis and major and minor ticks should be pointing inside the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
traindata = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
X = traindata.iloc[:,0]
X = np.array(X)
X = X*100
lr = list(range(0, 999))
lr = np.array(lr)
m = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
print(lr)
lr = np.array(lr)
plt.plot(lr,X,label='plot')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(lr), max(lr)+11, 100.0))
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(m), max(m)+1, 10.0))
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.ylabel('acc')
plt.xlabel('iter')
plt.show()
```

In x axis the 0 should start from corner. How do i do this. Also how to set all major and minor ticks to be appear inside instead of outside

Answer (score 3):

Use [`plt.margins(x=0)`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html). This will set the margin outside the drawn points to zero.

To set the direction of the ticks, it's probably best to use the rcParams `xtick.direction` and `ytick.direction`, which will set the direction for the complete script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'in'
plt.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'in'

plt.plot([2,1,3])

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.margins(x=0)

plt.show()
```